# Odoo 9.0 Traceback Errors on contact and Products

Tags: python-2.7, odoo, odoo-9

We are getting traceback errors whenever we select products or contact, our website apps runs Ok but we can't install e-commerce module which we remove recently what is causing it ? Please help

Odoo Server Error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openerp/http.py", line 648, in _handle_exception
return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openerp/http.py", line 685, in dispatch
result = self._call_function(**self.params)

 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openerp/http.py", line 321, in _call_function
return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)

 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openerp/service/model.py", line 118, in wrapper
return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)

 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openerp/http.py", line 314, in checked_call
result = self.endpoint(*a, **kw)

 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openerp/http.py", line 964, in __call__
return self.method(*args, **kw)

 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openerp/http.py", line 514, in response_wrap
response = f(*args, **kw)

 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openerp/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 828, in search_read
 return self.do_search_read(model, fields, offset, limit, domain, sort)

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openerp/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 849, in do_search_read
request.context)

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openerp/http.py", line 1069, in proxy
result = meth(cr, request.uid, *args, **kw)

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openerp/api.py", line 250, in wrapper
return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openerp/models.py", line 5297, in search_read
result = self.read(cr, uid, record_ids, fields, context=read_ctx)

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openerp/api.py", line 250, in wrapper
return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openerp/models.py", line 3203, in read
result = BaseModel.read(records, fields, load=load)

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openerp/api.py", line 248, in wrapper
return new_api(self, *args, **kwargs)

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openerp/models.py", line 3238, in read
self._read_from_database(stored, inherited)

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openerp/api.py", line 248, in wrapper
return new_api(self, *args, **kwargs)

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openerp/models.py", line 3429, in _read_from_database
res2 = self._columns[f].get(cr, self._model, ids, f, user, context=context, values=result)

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openerp/osv/fields.py", line 1501, in get
result = self._fnct(obj, cr, uid, ids, name, self._arg, context)

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openerp/addons/product/product.py", line 435, in _product_currency
res[product.id] = product.company_id.currency_id.id or main_company.currency_id.id

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openerp/fields.py", line 830, in __get__
self.determine_value(record)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openerp/fields.py", line 930, in determine_value
record._prefetch_field(self)

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openerp/api.py", line 248, in wrapper
return new_api(self, *args, **kwargs)

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openerp/models.py", line 3308, in _prefetch_field
result = records.read([f.name for f in fs], load='_classic_write')

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openerp/api.py", line 248, in wrapper
return new_api(self, *args, **kwargs)

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openerp/models.py", line 3238, in read
self._read_from_database(stored, inherited)

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openerp/api.py", line 248, in wrapper
return new_api(self, *args, **kwargs)

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openerp/models.py", line 3376, in _read_from_database
cr.execute(query_str, params)

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openerp/sql_db.py", line 141, in wrapper
return f(self, *args, **kwargs)

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openerp/sql_db.py", line 220, in execute
res = self._obj.execute(query, params)

ProgrammingError: column product_template.website_description does not exist
LINE 1: ...e" as "state","product_template"."type" as 
"type","product_t...
                                                         ^
```

Comment: i think some dependent module is missing  which is already stored in your db,update your db may remove this error

Comment: Thanks Mohammned,  l have updated the apps (assuming this is what you meant by updating db) I am still getting error. I also tried to install e-commerce afterwards and it didn't work. I should mention we tried to manually remove demo data - could this be causing it ?

Comment: When you start the server, read all the lines in the log to check if any module is not loaded. It's Error log with message 'Unmet dependances: ...."